# viewDidLoad() want to call everytime when I press tab cell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my `tableView`, when I press tab cell first time it calls `viewDidLoad()` but the other time that doesn't call `viewDidLoad()`. How to solve that problem. I want to call `viewDidLoad()` every time I press tab view in my code.

Comment: Why do you want `viewDidLoad` called every time? It should only be called once.

Comment: use viewWillAppear .....

Comment: viewdidload is only called once in its life time and basically for one time initialization , if it is required to do this thing again whenever view appear , best place is viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear .

Comment: viewDidLoad will only be called once. If you want some code to run every time view appears you should use either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method depending on situation.

Answer (score 4):

`ViewDidLoad` will be called when the view was loaded into memory. You want to use the `ViewWillAppear` function this will be called every time the view is about to get active.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
}
```

Comment: that's very useful answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much .. Helped me

Comment: @RashwanL Answers No2 is useful.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion `viewDidLoad()` will called only one time, 
`viewWillAppear()` will be called everytime page is loaded.
So you need to write source code to `viewWillAppear()` which might be call everytime.